# Can I refer to a static variable of a class without using its name? (for inheritance)

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Let's say I have some code:

```
class BuildingWithRecipe {
    static recipeType = ""
    findRecipe(){
        doStuffWith([not this].recipeType);
    }
}

class Furnace extends BuildingWithRecipe {
    static recipeType = "smelting"
}
```

I want to be able to access a static method of a class with a keyword inside of an instance method of that class, so when I extend BuildingWithRecipe(lets say with Furnace) I can simply set the static recipeType property and the findRecipe method will access Furnace.recipeType instead of BuildingWithRecipe.recipeType when called on an instance of Furnace.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why is `static recipeType` required inside `BuildingWithRecipe`?

Comment: @adiga I assume it's an example only. Maybe a bit too simplified, since it can easily be done as a constructor parameter to the base class and the child calls `super("smelting")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `this.constructor`:

```
findRecipe(){
    doStuffWith(this.constructor.recipeType);
}
```